# SQLPro for MSSQL date query off by one day

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm running the following query on a table from SQLPro for MSSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable where Date = '2016-06-28'
```

The Date column contains fields formatted as datetimes for example: '2016-06-27 19:00:00:000'. When I run the query it returns results whose entries in the Date column are one day earlier than the date I queried for. So in the above example all results returned have date '2016-06-27'. There is data for the date I'm looking for since if I query for '2016-06-29' I get the data for the 28th.

Further, when I query from a cursor using pymssql I get the data for the right dates so it seems like the issue is with SQLPro and not the database itself. Anyone know what's going on/how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you storing datetimes as strings that are "formatted" as datetimes? You should use the datetime datatype, that is why it exists.

Comment: Is there a possibility of using a DateTime type for the datetimes?

Comment: @SeanLange - are they strings?  How would the query shown return anything if the fields are strings?  or is SQLpro doing the conversion? maybe rounding to nearest whole date.  I don't see how the query shown would return any data if the filed was date, unless the time was midnight

Comment: The date column is stored as a smalldatetime(4). I do not manage the database, just usin' it

Comment: Sounds like a bug in SQLPro. Did you contact the vendor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer here. It is indeed a bug with SQLPro. I've sent a fix to @stableMatch which should resolve the issue.